# Can't redirect from http->https, error: :80: bind: permission denied

Tags: linux, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, https, traefik

Traefik redirection fails, http->https, i use this command to update/add the redirect feature, `helm upgrade traefik traefik/traefik -n traefik -f traefik-config-ha.yaml` and this is my traefik-config

```
additionalArguments:
  - "--metrics.prometheus.entryPoint=metrics"
  - "--metrics.prometheus=true"
  - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure"
  - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https"
  - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:80"
  - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443" 
  - "--entryPoints.metrics.address=:8082"
  - "--entrypoints.websecure.http.tls"
  - "--api.insecure=true"
  - "--api.dashboard=true"
  - "--accesslog=true"
  - "--log.level=DEBUG"

deployment:
  replicas: 3
  podAnnotations:
    prometheus.io/port: '8082'
    prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
traefik  Nov 30, 2020, 10:15:50 AM  2020/11/30 09:15:50 traefik.go:76: command traefik error: error while building entryPoint web: error preparing server: error opening listener: listen tcp :80: bind: permission denied
```

How would I solve this?

Comment: What are the privileges of the user you are running this with ?

Comment: @Pierre-AntoineGuillaume owner of the project in gcp  also i created the cluster

Comment: Your entrypoint `web` has no configured port number. Port 80 is configured for the websecure entrypoint. Not sure though if this is the source of the issue. Could also be a container user permission thing binding to a port less than 1024 with an unprivileged user. That would explain that it works with the modified port numbers of your answer. You could try moving to 80/443 for the two different(!) entrypoints to validate.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, but if there is anyone that can explained why it does work i would be grateful to hear it.

```
additionalArguments:
  - "--entrypoints.web.address=:8000"
  - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:8443"
  - "--metrics.prometheus.entryPoint=metrics"
  - "--metrics.prometheus=true"
  - "--entryPoints.metrics.address=:8082"
  - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=:443"
  - "--api.insecure=true"
  - "--api.dashboard=true"
  - "--accesslog=true"
  - "--log.level=DEBUG"

deployment:
  replicas: 3
  podAnnotations:
    prometheus.io/port: '8082'
    prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
```

Now it redirects from http - >https. It worked right away when i put this command  `"--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=:443"`